# Find sum of roots of complex equation $z^6 = z^{18} = -1$

Tags: complex-numbers

Find sum of roots of equation $z^6 = z^{18} = -1$

Roots of $z^6=-1$

[image: z^6]

Roots of $z^{18}=-1$

[image: z^18]

From the circle I can see, that:

$\{z : z^6=-1\} \cap \{z : z^{18}=-1\} = \{z : z^6=-1\}$

So, I can notice, that sum of roots $z^6=-1$ is equal to zero.
However, I solved that with help of WolframAlpha - drawing a circle with 18 points (or calculating all roots) is not very encouraging. Is there the more reliable method to solve such problem?

**Edit:** correct circles are:

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Comment: The easiest way to see the intersection is to note that if $z^6=-1$ then of necessity $z^{18}$ $= z^{6\cdot 3}$ $= \left(z^6\right)^3$ $= (-1)^3$ $=-1$, so every solution of $z^6=-1$ is automatically a solution of $z^{18}=-1$.

Comment: The plots are incorrect, this is what the correct images look like: http://www4b.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP26852010ac1ci9660bb00000282i25i2e7ih5039?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=64&w=240.&h=238.&cdf=Coordinates&cdf=Tooltips http://www4b.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP12411cf40f5d17bagb430000447c71i19fe898ce?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=33&w=240.&h=214.&cdf=Coordinates&cdf=Tooltips

Comment: It seems this site doesn't like the links being set up that way: the ellipses are being taken literally, so the pages are not being found.  But this isn't something WolframAlpha takes long to deal with if anyone wants to make the plots on their own.

Answer (score 4):

"Purity Of Essence, Mandrake, Purity Of Essence . . . "; General Jack Ripper, in Stanley Kubrick's *Dr. Strangelove* . . .

It is in the interest of preserving Mathematical Purity Of Essence that I feel obliged to point out that neither of the two root-plots provided by our OP stil is correct, for they each depict both $1$ and $-1$ as being roots of $z^6 = -1$ and $z^{18} = -1$ whereas in fact neither $1$ nor $-1$ are roots of either equation:  $1^6 = (-1)^6 = 1^{18} = (-1)^{18} = 1 \ne -1$.  I don't know what's up with Wolfram Alpha if it is saying that these are the root-plots of $z^6 = -1 = z^{18}$; but for all positive integers $n$ it is easy to type $z^n - 1$ instead of $z^n + 1$, so perhaps these plots are the output of an input error.  I would here recite that ancient mantra of computer programmers, GIGO, GIGO, GIGO:  Garbage In, Garbage Out, except that these cool plots are redeemable by a mere rotation of  either $\pi / 6$ or $\pi / 18$, that is, multiplication of all their complex-valued points by $e^{i\pi / 6}$ or $e^{i \pi /18}$, according to whether the plot corresponds to the equation $z^6 = 1$ or $z^{18} = 1$, respectively.  Indeed, if $z^6 = 1$ then $(e^{i\pi / 6}z)^6 = e^{i\pi}z^6 = (-1)1 = -1$, with a similar result holding in the case $z^{18} = 1$.  So rather than being garbage, these plots are merely like broken toys which can easily be fixed with some magic tape or a dab of glue.

Having said these things, there is an easy way to determine the sum of the roots of *any* equation of the form $z^n + a = 0$, for any integer $n \ge 1$ and any $a \in \Bbb C$.  If $n = 1$, then $z = -a$, so the sum is $-a$ in this case.  For $n \ge 2$, let $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, . . . \alpha_n$ be the roots of $z^n + a = 0$.  Then we can write $z^n + a$ as the product

$z^n + a = \prod_1^n (z - \alpha_i), \tag{1}$

and when the right-hand side is multiplied out we obtain

$z^n + a = \prod_1^n (z - \alpha_i) = z^n - (\sum_1^n \alpha_i)z^{n - 1} + \sum_{i, j = 1, i \ne j}^n \alpha_i \alpha_j + . . . + (-1)^n \prod_1^n \alpha_i; \tag{2}$

comparing coefficients we see that $\sum_1^n \alpha_i = 0$, $(-1)^n \prod_1^n \alpha_i = a$, and a host of other things besides.  Much simpler than working with trigonometric polynomials, as I think you will probably agree!  Reliable, too!

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: @ stil:  this answer also helps with your other question in re. product of roots of $z^{12} = -i$!

Comment: That introduction was so poetic and hard to understand :P

Comment: @ qwr:  I guess you'd have to have seen *Dr. Strangelove*!  I take your remarks as a compliment.  Thanks! ;-) B-)

Comment: @RecklessReckoner:  that's what I think too, but I couldn't resist the chance to take a jibe.  I noted the probable source of error in my post, in any event.

Answer (score 1):

The sum of the roots is the sum of the cosines and sines: $\sin(\pi/9) = -\sin(\pi/9) = -\sin(17\pi/9)$ and so forth. This gives the imaginary part of the sum as $0$; similarly, $\cos(\pi/9) = -\cos(8\pi/9)$ and so forth; so the real part is also $0$. Just think in terms of components.

Answer (score 1):

If $\alpha$ is a root, $-\alpha$ is a different root. Both sum up to $0$